# Decode large bitmap on Android

Tags: android, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory

I know it's a very common question, but I didnt manage to fix it. I am using Android Volley to download the image JPEG content over HTTP, I get the byte array, then in my "parse" method, who have to transforme the byte array into Bitmap:

```
private Bitmap doParse(NetworkResponse response)
{
    int scaleFactor = 1;
    BitmapFactory.Options decodeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    decodeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds    = false;
    decodeOptions.inPreferredConfig     = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

    do
    {
        byte[] data = response.data.clone();

        decodeOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;

        try
        {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, decodeOptions);
        }
        catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
        {
            scaleFactor *= 2;

            bitmap = null;
        }
    }
    while (bitmap == null && scaleFactor < 128);

    return bitmap;
}
```

What I want is: "If the bitmap is too large (OutOfMemory thrown), increase scaleFactor and re-try to decode".

My problem is an empty bitmap (not null) is returned, where as it works fine if I set the scaleFactor to 8 at the first "loop".

Comment: where are you using decodeOptions? it looks like you're assigning it, but never using it

Comment: Sorry, edited code example. (I tried so many things ^^)

Comment: are you sure about that part: `byte[] data = response.data.clone();`? Not entirely sure how `clone` works on arrays. (though the fact that a bitmap is decoded should demonstrate that it kind of works)

Comment: I tried without .clone(), same thing, I believe BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray does something with data content that break the byte data or something.